# How to add more time into current timestamp of Postman?

Tags: postman

I know I am able to add current timestamp into Request like this:

`postman.setEnvironmentVariable('pickUpTime',(new Date()).toISOString());`

However, I want to add 10min later to the current timestamp of Postman. How can I do that?

Seems I am not able to do it like this:

`postman.setEnvironmentVariable('pickUpTime',(new Date() + 10000).toISOString());`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `add` function of [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) within Postman, it makes this type of thing so simple and easy to manage.

```
var moment = require("moment")

pm.environment.set('pickUpTime', moment().add(10, 'minutes').toISOString())
```

This will set this value to an environment variable, using the the newer syntax.