# How to retrieve current time stamp, add X hours to it, and then store as a variable in POSTMAN?

Tags: json, api, testing, timestamp, postman

I'm writing POSTMAN tests.
It takes a current time stamp from my account which is under UTC 00.
 I need to make it +11 hours and store it as a variable.

I can extract a current time frame under UTC 00 and store it as a global variable,
 but it misses a step for adding 11 hours to it.

```
var current_timestamp = new Date();
pm.globals.set("current_timestamp", current_timestamp.toISOString());
```

**Actual stored variable:**
2019-01-14T01:28:11.068Z
**Expected stored variable:**
2019-01-14T12:28:11.068Z

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49637741/how-to-add-more-time-into-current-timestamp-of-postman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `.setHours()`

```
var current_timestamp = new Date();
console.log(current_timestamp.toISOString())
// 2019-01-14T06:13:47.757Z
current_timestamp.setHours(current_timestamp.getHours() + 11); 
console.log(current_timestamp.toISOString())
// 2019-01-14T17:13:47.757Z

pm.globals.set("current_timestamp", current_timestamp.toISOString())
```

Answer (score 0):

Postman supports [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) in scripts. Here is an example of how you might use it:

```
var moment = require('moment')
pm.globals.set('endOfDayWeekFromNowUTC', moment().endOf('day').add(1, 'weeks').utc().format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss'))
```

[Here is some information on how to parse dates with moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/).